# How to create a sql server connection in mobile report publisher

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I did a fresh install of SQL 2016 RC1.  Report Builder works (for paginated reports).  But I can't get the Mobile Report Publisher to create a connection to from my laptop to the sql instance.  When I try to connect to the server I get a "Server Error" Unable to connect to remote server.  I'm running the latest preview 3 of mobile publisher.  I've tried server/reportserver & server/reports for a server address, no luck.  I get a different error if I uncheck the option to use a secure connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so, the reports_preview is gone.  And after lots of trial and error, the url needs to include the port:

sqlrpt16-1:80/Reports/

I had to uncheck the Use secure connection option, which probably uses https, which i didn't configure during setup.

Comment: Thanks - I was having the same issues, having just installed RC2.  There is a lack of documentation at present.  No doubt others will be experiencing similar issues.

Comment: Hello sqlpadawan, is it necessary to install SQL 2016 for running mobile report publisher??

Comment: No, you don't need to install SQL to use the mobile report publisher.

Comment: Thanks buddy but then how can i connect with data from sql server 2012 to Report publisher? i already tried server address but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

please try connecting to the new portal url : /reports_preview.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.  It looks like the report_preview was removed in the RC1 release (at least there isn't a virtual directory).  I'm going to install the mobile report publisher on the server and try and connect locally.